Get the AMCSECAUTH cookie from microsoft login results in infinite redirect that is unfollowable
When attempting to grab the AMCSECAUTH cookie from the finished login (which ive managed to do) it gets stuck in a infinite loop. I attempted to follow this loop manually but i stop on the 3rd request at a get request with a 200 response code. there is a wreply parameter in the get request header that i think is the reason for me stopping on a certain point without ever attaining the amcsecauth. could be wrong but i think get requests (response2, response3) all reply to the main request (response) and then it is finalized but python requests sends requests 1 by 1 (or at least to my knowledge). Here is my code:
code here since my ticket got marked as spam when i included it: https://pastecode.io/s/vqe4pwgr
was expecting to follow the redirect manually and obtain the AMCSECAUTH cookie which is obtained upon finishing the login system at login.live.com (or other aliases) but instead i stop at response3 with no further redirects and a status code of 200.
UPDATE
I have managed to follow the redirects yet i still dont the get expected cookies heres my code:
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin

# session thingy
session = requests.Session()

# headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Referer": "https://login.live.com/",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "Priority": "u=1"
}

# urls
url1 = "https://account.microsoft.com/auth/complete-silent-signin?ru=https://account.microsoft.com/?lang=en-US&refd=account.live.com&refp=landing&mkt=EN-US&wa=wsignin1.0"
url2 = "https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=153&checkda=1&ct=1717842587&rver=7.5.2112.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Fauth%2Fcomplete-silent-signin%3Fru%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.microsoft.com%252Fauth%252Fcomplete-silent-signin%253Fru%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Faccount.microsoft.com%25252F%25253Flang%25253Den-US%252526refd%25253Daccount.live.com%252526refp%25253Dlanding%252526mkt%25253DEN-US%2526wa%253Dwsignin1.0%2526refd%253Dlogin.live.com&lc=1033&id=292666"
url3 = 'https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=153&checkda=1&ct=1717842679&rver=7.5.2112.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https:%2F%2Faccount.microsoft.com%2Fauth%2Fcomplete-silent-signin%3Fru%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccount.microsoft.com%252Fauth%252Fcomplete-silent-signin%253Fru%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Faccount.microsoft.com%25252F%25253Flang%25253Den-US%252526refd%25253Daccount.live.com%252526refp%25253Dlanding%252526mkt%25253DEN-US%2526wa%253Dwsignin1.0%2526refd%253Dlogin.live.com&lc=1033&id=292666'

data = {
    "NAPExp": "Mon, 16-Sep-2024 16:47:43 GMT",
    "pprid": "8aa4ef361bf0126b",
    "NAP": "V%3D1.9%26E%3D1d82%26C%3D03CX5YHwoDCL3qwIisSUAxJ0Z5znpZadA9XJHxKqyPEsVE_Q-3ylnQ%26W%3D1",
    "ANON": "A%3DCE6B3E29A1B772C6470FB4C4FFFFFFFF%26E%3D1ddc%26W%3D1",
    "ANONExp": "Wed, 25-Dec-2024 17:47:43 GMT",
    "t": "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"
}

# Initial request
response = session.post(url1, data=data, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)

# Base URL for resolving relative redirects
base_url = url1

# Follow redirects manually
redirect_count = 0
while response.is_redirect or response.is_permanent_redirect:
    redirect_count += 1
    redirect_url = response.headers['Location']
    full_redirect_url = urljoin(base_url, redirect_url)
    print(f"Redirect {redirect_count}: {full_redirect_url}")
    response = session.get(full_redirect_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    base_url = full_redirect_url

response2 = session.get(url2, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
while response2.is_redirect or response2.is_permanent_redirect:
    redirect_url = response2.headers['Location']
    full_redirect_url = urljoin(base_url, redirect_url)
    print(f"Redirecting to: {full_redirect_url}")
    response2 = session.get(full_redirect_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    base_url = full_redirect_url

response3 = session.get(url3, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
if response3.is_redirect or response3.is_permanent_redirect:
    redirect_url = response3.headers['Location']
    full_redirect_url = urljoin(base_url, redirect_url)
    print(f"Redirecting to: {full_redirect_url}")
    response3 = session.get(full_redirect_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

# Print cookies
print("Cookies after final request:")
for cookie in session.cookies:
    print(f"{cookie.name}: {cookie.value}")

# Check for AMCSECAUTH cookie
if 'AMCSECAUTH' in session.cookies:
    print("AMCSECAUTH cookie found!")
else:
    print("AMCSECAUTH cookie not found.")
    print(response.headers)
    print(response2.headers)
    print(response3.headers)

